# Why does CLion not instantly generate configuration files in my new project?

Tags: java, clion, intellij-plugin

I'm currently working on a CLion Plugin, which involves creating a new Project. Once it's created, I open up a new window with said project. My problem is that CLion only seems to generate the `.iml` and `modules.xml` files after I close and reopen the project. My question is, what am I missing or doing wrong?

My steps so far:

1. I create the necessary project root directory
2. I call `ProjectManager.getInstance().createProject(projectName, projectPath)` which returns a Project object.
3. I open the project in a new Window by calling `ProjectManager.getInstance().loadAndOpenProject(project.getPresentableUrl())`

A new window opens but the config files mentioned above are not generated. Only if I close the project and reopen it, the config files are generated and cmake support is enabled.

My thoughts on this:
I would probably need to create a module inside the project? But then what exactly is the right way to do this programmatically? In this case I would like to create a C Module but I found nothing showing me how to do this. Following the tutorial on the intellij sdk documentation by creating a modulebuilder doesn't seem to work in CLion. The only source code I found while searching the internet is the CLion Arduino Plugin, which quite frankly has the same problem.

Anything pointing me in the right direction on this one would be greatly appreciated. Is there any documentation on how to do this kind of thing?Also this is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow, so any feedback on posting here is also appreciated.